# Issue with unsigned long long int with sparc assembly code on sparc64

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, sparc

I have an issue with the C code below into which I have included Sparc Assembly. The code is compiled and running on Debian 9.0 Sparc64. It does a simple summation and print the result of this sum which equals to `nLoop`.

The problem is that for an initial number of iterations greater than 1e+9, the final sum at the end is systematically equal to 1410065408 : I don't understand why since I put explicitly `unsigned long long int` type for `sum` variable and so `sum` can be in `[0, +18,446,744,073,709,551,615]` range.

For example, for `nLoop = 1e+9`, I expect `sum` to be equal to `1e+9`.

Does issue come rather from included Assembly Sparc code which could not handle 64 bits variables (in input or output) ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i;
  // Init sum
  unsigned long long int sum = 0ULL;
  // Number of iterations
  unsigned long long int nLoop = 10000000000ULL;

   // Loop with Sparc assembly into C source
   asm volatile ("clr %%g1\n\t"
                 "clr %%g2\n\t"
                 "mov %1, %%g1\n" // %1 = input parameter
                 "loop:\n\t"
                 "add %%g2, 1, %%g2\n\t"
                 "subcc %%g1, 1, %%g1\n\t"
                 "bne loop\n\t"
                 "nop\n\t"
                 "mov %%g2, %0\n" // %0 = output parameter
                 : "=r" (sum)     // output
                 : "r" (nLoop)    // input
                 : "g1", "g2");   // clobbers

  // Print results
  printf("Sum = %llu\n", sum);

  return 0;

}
```

How to fix this problem of range and allow to use 64 bits variables into Sparc Assembly code ?

PS: I tried to compile with gcc -m64, issue remains.

### Update 1

As requested by @zwol, below is the output Assembly Sparc code generated with : `gcc -O2 -m64 -S loop.c -o loop.s`

```
        .file   "loop.c"
        .section        ".text"
        .section        .rodata.str1.8,"aMS",@progbits,1
        .align 8
.LC0:
        .asciz  "Sum = %llu\n"
        .section        .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
        .align 4
        .global main
        .type   main, #function
        .proc   04
main:
        .register       %g2, #scratch
        save    %sp, -176, %sp
        sethi   %hi(_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_-4), %l7
        call    __sparc_get_pc_thunk.l7
         add    %l7, %lo(_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+4), %l7
        sethi   %hi(9764864), %o1
        or      %o1, 761, %o1
        sllx    %o1, 10, %o1
#APP
! 13 "loop.c" 1
        clr %g1
        clr %g2
        mov %o1, %g1
loop:
        add %g2, 1, %g2
        subcc %g1, 1, %g1
        bne loop
        nop
        mov %g2, %o1

! 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
        mov     0, %i0
        sethi   %gdop_hix22(.LC0), %o0
        xor     %o0, %gdop_lox10(.LC0), %o0
        call    printf, 0
         ldx    [%l7 + %o0], %o0, %gdop(.LC0)
        return  %i7+8
         nop
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (Debian 7.3.0-15) 7.3.0"
        .section        .text.__sparc_get_pc_thunk.l7,"axG",@progbits,__sparc_get_pc_thunk.l7,comdat
        .align 4
        .weak   __sparc_get_pc_thunk.l7
        .hidden __sparc_get_pc_thunk.l7
        .type   __sparc_get_pc_thunk.l7, #function
        .proc   020
__sparc_get_pc_thunk.l7:
        jmp     %o7+8
         add    %o7, %l7, %l7
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

**UPDATE 2:**

As suggested by @Martin Rosenau, I did following modifications :

```
loop:
        add %g2, 1, %g2
        subcc %g1, 1, %g1
        bpne %icc, loop
        bpne %xcc, loop
        nop
        mov %g2, %o1
```

But at the compilation, I get :

```
Error: Unknown opcode: `bpne'
```

What could be the reason for this compilation error ?

Comment: Please compile this program with `gcc -O2 -m64 -S` and edit the contents of the resulting `.s` file into the question.

Comment: For verification, have you tried to also write `nLoop`? Something like this: `printf("nLoop = %llu, Sum = %llu\n", nLoop, sum);`. C is notorious for not telling you if number wrapping happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> subcc %%g1, 1, %%g1
> bne loop
> ```

Your problem is the `bne` instruction:

Unlike the x86-64 CPU Sparc64 CPUs don't have different instructions for 32- and 64-bit subtraction:

If you want subtract 1 from 0x12345678 the result is 0x12345677. If you subtract 1 from 0xF00D**12345678** the result is 0xF00D**12345677** so if you only use the lower 32 bits of a register a 64-bit subtraction has the same effect as the 32-bit subtraction.

Therefore the Sparc64 CPUs do not have different instructions for 64-bit and 32-bit addition, subtraction, multiplication, left shift etc.

These CPUs have different instructions for 32-bit and 64-bit operations when the upper 32 bits influence the lower 32 bits (e.g. right shift).

However the **zero flag** depends on the result of the `subcc` operation.

To solve this problem the Sparc64 CPUs have each of the integer flags (zero, overflow, carry, sign) twice:

The **32-bit zero flag** will be set if the lower 32 bits of a register are zero; the **64-bit zero flag** will be set if all 64 bits of a register are zero.

To be compatible with existing 32-bit programs the `bne` instruction will check the 32-bit zero flag, not the 64-bit zero flag.

> is systematically equal to 1410065408

1e10 = 0x200000000 + 1410065408 so after 1410065408 steps the value 0x200000000 is reached which has the lower 32 bits set to 0 and `bne` will not jump any more.

However for 1e11 you should not get 1410065408 but 1215752192 as a result because 1e11 = 0x1700000000 + 1215752192.

> `bne`

There is a new instruction named `bpne` which has up to 4 arguments!

In the simplest variant (with only two arguments) the instruction should (I have not used Sparc for 5 years now, so I'm not sure) work like this:

```
bpne %icc, loop   # Like bne (based on the 32-bit result)
bpne %xcc, loop   # Like bne, but based on the 64-bit result
```

**EDIT**

> ```
> Error: Unknown opcode: 'bpne'
> ```

I just tried using GNU assembler:

GNU assembler names the new instruction `bne` - just like the old one:

```
bne loop         # Old variant
bne %icc, loop   # New variant based on the 32-bit result
bne %xcc, loop   # (New variant) Based on the 64-bit result
```

> ```
>   subcc %g1, 1, %g1
>   bpne %icc, loop
>   bpne %xcc, loop
>   nop
> ```

The first `bpne` (or `bne`) makes no sense: Whenever the first line would do the jump the second line would also jump. And if you don't use `.reorder` (however this is the default) you would also need to add a `nop` between the two branch instructions...

The code should look like this (assuming your assembler also names `bpne` `bne`):

```
   subcc %g1, 1, %g1
   bne %xcc, loop
   nop
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunately, I get " `Error: Unknown opcode: 'bpne'` " at the compilation. I have used `bpne` instruction like : loop:
`loop:
        add %g2, 1, %g2
        subcc %g1, 1, %g1
        bpne %icc, loop
        bpne %xcc, loop
        nop
        mov %g2, %o1`

Comment: -@Martinc Rosenau : could you take a look please on my **UPDATE 2** ?

Answer (score 0):

Try "bne %xcc, loop" which should branch based on the 64 bit result.